# pandas fill the column values with min function

Tags: python, pandas, min

I have a dataframe with 2 columns and I need to add 3rd column 'start'. However my code for some reason doesn't work and I am not sure why. Here is my code

```
df.loc[df.type=='C', 'start']= min(-1+df['dq']-3,4)
df.loc[df.type=='A', 'start']= min(-3+df['dq']-3,4)
df.loc[df.type=='B', 'start']= min(-3+df['dq']-5,4)

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), 
a.any() or a.all().
```

and the dataset looks like this:

```
type        dq
A            3
A            4
B            8
C            3
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

The error is being raised because first argument you pass to `min()` is a Series and the second (4) is an `int`.

Since you're using `min` to replace values greater than 4 with 4, you can just replace it once at the end using `where`:

```
df.loc[df.type=='C', 'start'] = -1+df['dq']-3
df.loc[df.type=='A', 'start'] = -3+df['dq']-3
df.loc[df.type=='B', 'start'] = -3+df['dq']-5
df["start"] = df["start"].where(df["start"]<4,other=4)

>>> df
  type  dq  start
0    A   3     -3
1    A   4     -2
2    B   8      0
3    C   3     -1
```

Another (perhaps cleaner) way of getting your column would be to use `numpy.select`, like so:

```
import numpy as np

df["start"] = np.select([df["type"]=="A", df["type"]=="B", df["type"]=="C"],
                        [df['dq']-6, df["dq"]-8, df["dq"]-4])
df["start"] = df["start"].where(df["start"]<4, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a Series with min. Instead, you can do:

```
s = (df['dq'] - df['type'].map({'A': 6, 'B': 8, 'C': 4}))
df['start'] = s.where(s<4, 4)
```

output:

```
  type  dq  start
0    A   3     -3
1    A   4     -2
2    B   8      0
3    C   3     -1
```